# Amazon MWS XML how to specify shipping template

Tags: amazon-mws

Would appreciate some sample XML. I simply want to specify which shipping template should apply to any given product.

Amazon support pointed me to https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Override.xsd but I fail to see how to specify the shipping template.

I was hoping there was something simple that could be included as part of `_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_` such as

`<shipping_template>template1</shipping_template>`

but I don't see that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You should use the _POST_PRODUCT_DATA_

Here is the xml example that works for amazon.com:

```
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion><MerchantIdentifier>XYZ</MerchantIdentifier></Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>PartialUpdate</OperationType>
    <Product><SKU>YOURSKUNAME</SKU>
    <DescriptionData>
    <Title>Sometitle</Title><MerchantShippingGroupName>SHIPPINGTEMPLATENAME</MerchantShippingGroupName></DescriptionData>
    </Product>
    </Message>
    </AmazonEnvelope>
```

Unfortunately it looks like the `<Title>` is mandatory even if you just want to change shipping template. If you want to change multiple skus at once just add more `<Message>` to the feed.

Comment: Tested without sending Title, response from Amazon:

    XML Parsing Error at Line 1, Column 452: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MerchantShippingGroupName'. One of '{Title}' is expected.

Comment: As stupid as this sounds, Amazon requires you to include the `<Title>` tag, with a value, when performing a `_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_` request. Every when simply trying to specify `<MerchantShippingGroupName>`.

Answer (score -3):

I Use this XML Feed for shipping orders and it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>

<Message>
<MessageID>MESSAGE_ID2</MessageID>
<OrderFulfillment>
<AmazonOrderID>123-1234567-1234567</AmazonOrderID>
<FulfillmentDate>SHIP_DATE</FulfillmentDate> //$ship_date = date("c");
<FulfillmentData>
<CarrierCode>Royal Mail</CarrierCode>
</FulfillmentData>
</OrderFulfillment>
</Message>

<Message>
<MessageID>MESSAGE_ID2</MessageID>
<OrderFulfillment>
<AmazonOrderID>321-7654321-7654321</AmazonOrderID>
<FulfillmentDate>SHIP_DATE</FulfillmentDate> //$ship_date = date("c");
<FulfillmentData>
<CarrierCode>Royal Mail</CarrierCode>
</FulfillmentData>
</OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
.
.
.    
</AmazonEnvelope>


$parameters = array(
        'Merchant' => $MERCHANT_ID,
        'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
        'FeedType' => '_POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_',
        'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
        'PurgeAndReplace' => false, //Leave this PurgeAndReplace to false so that it want replace whole product in amazon inventory
        'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true))
    );

    rewind($feedHandle);
    $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);

    $return_feed = invokeSubmitFeed($service, $request);

    fclose($feedHandle);
```

Comment: What does an order have to do with product shipping template?!